# Android printing json array output on a textview

Tags: java, android, json

I have an android app that should parse json array output from a web service 
I tested the output with a java application and it works fine.
My purpose here to print  one of the output in a textview but I failed

class JsonReader

```
public class JsonReader 
{
private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int cp;
         while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1)
         {
         sb.append((char) cp);
                              }
          return sb.toString();
                                      }

      public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException
      {
       InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
       try 
       {
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
       String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
        return json;
        }
        finally 
        {
          is.close();
        }
           }

      public JsonReader() throws JSONException, IOException
      {

      }  

      }
```

MainActivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    try
    {
    JsonReader r = new JsonReader();
    JSONArray json = r.readJsonFromUrl ("http://localhost:8888/derdeery/zaki.php");

 for (int i =1; i < json.length(); ++i)
 {
 JSONObject  jsons =json.getJSONObject(i);

 int service_ID = jsons.getInt("service_ID");
 String Site_comment = jsons.getString("site_comment");
 String Img_Link = jsons.getString("img_link"); 
 uid.setText(Site_comment);

}

    }
catch(Exception e)
       { }}}
```

My xml file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: Is it TextView or EditText?

Comment: Simply stating "I failed" is not sufficient. Explain in details what your issue is and what you've attempted in order to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Need to do following changes to get it work:

**1.** `editText1` is `EditText` instead of `TextView`. so use same view in code for casting which is used in xml file:

```
final EditText uid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

**2.** Currently doing network operation(API call) on UI Thread which will cause ANR Dialog or `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if network operation(API call) take more time.

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s `doInBackground` method for doing network operation(API call) and `onPostExecute` for updating UI with result of `doInBackground` method.